# Powershell and Microsoft Edge Automation

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I am trying to create a script that automatically opens Microsoft Edge into developer mode, and performs a bing search in the existing tab.

I have managed to get as far as starting Edge and placing the tab into developer mode, however if ITry and add commands to complete a bing search it opens a secondary tab, which is not in developer mode.

My goals are-
Opens MSEDGE as a maximised window
-Enables Developer Mode Options in the current tab (F12) keystroke
-Completes a bing search in the current tab (for argument sake "https://www.bing.com/search?q=1" )

My code so far consists of-

```
& "C:\Program Files  (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ArgumentList --profile-directory="Profile 3"
Sleep 5 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Google - Microsoft Edge') 
$wshell.SendKeys('{F12}')
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks
ElDaTrain

Comment: Just curious. What OS are you running? As that is not the location or name of MSEdge, on WIn10. So, I am curious how this is even working for you at the point you say you've achieved thus far. As is, what you've posted, just fails immediately on any version of  Win10 I have in my lab. Unless you've messed with the registry or the like.

Answer (score 3):

From the description, I understand that you want to launch the Edge Chromium browser using Powershell then launch the developer tools and visit a specific URL.

You can try to launch the Edge browser with a URL and then try to open developer tools.

Please refer to the example below.

```
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msedge","https://www.bing.com/search?q=1")

Sleep 3 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Bing') 
$wshell.SendKeys('{F12}')
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Make sure first you manually launch the Edge browser in maximized mode and close it then try to run the above script will launch the Edge browser in maximized mode.

If you want to perform some advanced automation then it is recommended to use the [MS Webdriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Comment: @ortiga, could you please provide more details regarding your question? it could help us understand it in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Can this script be used with the coulto browser, in the background?

Comment: It will not be possible to using the above script. You could use the Microsoft WebDriver to achieve that requirement. You could refer to the link I shared in my answer above.

Comment: Could you help me with this question? https://superuser.com/questions/1734886/how-to-fill-fields-of-a-dialog-in-ie-with-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment. That is not the location of MSEdge, at least not on Win10.

Doing this...

```
& "C:\Program Files  (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
```

... on a default Win10 install will simply error out.

> & : The term 'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe' is not recognized as the
> name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Edge is a modern app and they are located in a special folder.

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name '*edge*' | 
Select-Object -Property Name, InstallLocation
<#
Name                                  InstallLocation                                                          
----                                  ---------------                                                          
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge               C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe              
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe
#>
```

Also, the app name you are using is not valid:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:windir\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" -Filter '*edge*'

# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name 
----                 -------------         ------ ---- 
-a----        10/15/2020  12:53 AM       16305480 MicrosoftEdge.exe
#>
```

Nonetheless, by design, Microsoft Edge does not support the COM automation as IE does. You need to use this WebDriver, which you need to download.

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212

See details on the Microsoft Edge WebDrive page.

> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver

All that being said you can launch MSEdge from PowerShell using a link.

Example - default desktop link

```
& (Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*edge*').FullName
```

Or

```
Start-Process -FilePath (Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*edge*').FullName
```

Once MS Edge is open and visible, then you can use SendKeys to mess with it.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
& (Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*edge*').FullName
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F12}')
```

Lastly, there is no need to start MSEdge separately for your use case. Just start the URL, and it will start your default browser.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Start-Process -FilePath 'https://www.google.com'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F12}')
```

Comment: Just a note that in Windows 10 the Edge modern app is being replaced by the Chromium build, which is installed in `%ProgramFiles(x86)` on x64 systems.